# iOS: Is there a way to alter the color of every pixel on the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor, uiwindow

How does apple alter the color of every single pixel on the screen (i.e. grayscale / inversion of colors), regardless of what object the color belongs to. It obviously isn't reading background color properties since it even affects images, as well.

How would one approach this?

To clarify my question, how can I change the intensity / hue of every pixel on the screen, similar to how [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) does it?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Is there a specific way in which you want to alter the pixels? Do you want to do this in an app or also for other apps? And what do you mean with at once? In one frame? In one line of code? With a single instruction to the GPU?

Comment: Thanks @NikolaiRuhe for taking the time to comment. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How does apple alter the color of every single pixel on the screen?

Apple probably uses an API called [`CGSetDisplayTransferByTable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001070-CH202-F17122) which is not publicly available on iOS.

The display transfer table controls how each possible value in each of the three RGB channels is displayed on screen and can convert it to a different value. It works similar to Photoshop's "Curves" tool. By using the right transfer table it's possible to invert the screen, adjust the hue or enhance contrast.

Since the transfer table is part of the graphics hardware and is always active, there's zero performance overhead involved. On Mac OS there are actually two transfer tables: one for the application and one for the OS.

> how can I change the intensity / hue of every pixel on the screen

Without jailbreak, you can't.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai is this similar to LUT?

Comment: I don't know if you have something more special in mind that the generic term of a common lookup table. If not, yes, Quartz Display Services probably uses a LUT to implement the display transfer APIs.